# MAXIFS multiple criteria ignoring NA() data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the maximum value of a column within a certain range and ignore the NA() values that are in the column. All of the data in the column that is not NA() is greater than zero. I have tried ignoring the `NA(), >=0` and the AGGREGATE function does not have the `MAXIFS` only the MAX function.

```
=MAXIFS(SR_Layer2,Chainage,">="&D12,Chainage,"<="&E12,SR_Layer2,"<>NA()")
=MAXIFS(SR_Layer2,Chainage,">="&D12,Chainage,"<="&E12,SR_Layer2,">=0")
```

It displays the `#VALUE!`

Comment: SR_Layer2 and Chainage must have the same size and shape, or you will get #Value

Answer (score 2):

Try: `=MAXIFS(A2:A6,A2:A6,"<>" & "#N/A")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is the correct answer, because it selects max even if all the range values were negative.

Answer (score 0):

Well, tried this and it seems to work fine:

```
=MAXIFS(A1:A11,A1:A11,">"&0)
```

[image]